# Best way to push the project folder into GitHub

Tags: python, shell, github

I have a python project and i am trying to write a script to push the project folder into git

What are the steps that should be taken

I have tried
https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/automate-project-github-setup-mac/
but cant seem to fix it

Comment: You should explain your specific problem and what have you tried

Comment: My problem is to make a script to push the actual project to github

Comment: What was the issue that you had from the script in that tutorial?

Comment: Incidentally, I'd be wary about *automating* pushing stuff to github.  Most decent editors have git integration, but you can't *automate* commiting: you have to do it manually, or it's pretty worthless. Ditto pushing/pulling/merging/branching.  `git push` is not so terribly hard to do, but any automated solution would either be an alias for `git push` or have to be ridiculously complicated to handle all the edge cases when you have incompatible changes

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need to create a repo on the Github UI.
After creating the repo, Github will give you a URL to that repo.
Assuming you have SSH keys setup, you'll then be able to use that URL to push your commits like so:

On a project directory:

```sh
git init  # initialize a repo; create a .git folder with git internal data
git add file1.py file2.sh file3.js README.md  # choose which files you'd like to upload
git commit -m "Add project files"  # create a commit
git remote add origin "github repo url"
git push  # upload commit to Github
```

Automating this "first push" for several projects is relatively easy.
Just be careful with what files you're going to git add. Git is not designed to version binaries like images, pdfs, etc.

Comment: Can i write the same in shell script

Comment: Sure. Those are all bash commands. But you'll need to create your repos with the same name as the folders they're in if you intend to use the folder name to parametrize the Github repo URL.

Comment: Tip: if all your repos are of the same language (e.g.: python), add the [standard python gitignore](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Python.gitignore) on all those folders. Then you'll be able to run `git add .gitignore ; git add .` instead of manually selecting files.

Answer (score 0):

I use this code. Assuming you have SSH keys setup.

```
import os
from datetime import datetime

current_time = datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S")


os.system("git init")
os.system("git remote rm origin")
os.system("git remote add origin git@github.com:user/repository.git")
os.system('git config --global user.email "email@example.com"')
os.system('git config --global user.name "username"')
os.system("git rm -r --cached .")
os.system("git add .")
git_commit_with_time = f'git commit -m "update:{current_time}"'
os.system(git_commit_with_time)
os.system("git push -f --set-upstream origin master")
```

You can also customize it according to you.

You can use something else instead of the `current_time` in the commit.

I have been using this for many months and I found it the best way.
Because since I have automated the task, I have not had any problem till date.